# Append Database tables a - e?

Tags: database-design

A beginners question, I have 5 tables a - e, all with the same column headings but different values. I want to make one table from the 5 tables, but keeping the row information the same is it possible and how to do it?

Thanks
CKeane.

Comment: Which database and do you actually need to store the table data all together or just see it all at once ie if the latter you can have a view union-ing across the tables

Comment: All tables are in the one database, however I want to put them in one table instead of 5. For example have table_a all rows,table_b all rows etc...

Comment: I meant SQL server/oracle/MySQL etc. in theory you can just do something like "insert into combinedTable (col1, col2...) select col1, col2... from a union select col1, col2... from b etc. Replace column list with actual columns and include all tables

Comment: Ah sorry, I am using a SAS front end that connects to a database system but not sure which type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
INSERT INTO <target_table>
SELECT * FROM <source_table1>
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM <source_table2>
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM <source_table3>
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM <source_table4>
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM <source_table5>
```

Comment: Yes Something like this. I would vote up but short on reputation.

Comment: @Ckeane You can _accept_ what you consider to be the most helpful answer, regardless of the reputation.